# How can I hide the advertisement blocker button in Midori's headerbar?

Tags: midori

I'm currently using Midori with headerbar support from the elementary OS Daily PPA. Is there any way to hide the advertisement blocker button next to the menu button in the headerbar, without deactivating the extension?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the advertisement blocker extension in preferences:

1. Open the gear menu
2. Select "Preferences"
3. Select the "Extensions" tab
4. Un-check "Advertisement blocker"

Comment: I don't think that's possible.